# MySQL, Why doesn't my update query work?

Tags: mysql, sql-update

I'm made a copy of my MySQL database in MS Access as I was sure my query would work.

Heres my query

```
 UPDATE Pads RIGHT JOIN Fix ON Pads.PadID = Fix.PadID 
 SET Pads.RemoveMeDate = '1999-01-01 00:00:00'
```

This query work in MS Access, but not in MySQL.

How do I fix this ? and why doesn't it work ?

EDIT
*** When I say my query doesn't work, I mean no rows affected, when there are matching records ... ***

Comment: If your rows aren't matching, then show us your database schema

Comment: While reqriting that query on my own, I came up with the same as yours... (UPDATE Pads
RIGHT JOIN Fix ON Pads.PadID = Fix.PadID
SET Pads.RemoveDate = '1999-01-01 00:00:00'). Could you please tell us, whats the SQL error? (if there is any, since query looks OK)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 UPDATE Pads, Fix
 SET Pads.RemoveMeDate = '1999-01-01 00:00:00'
 WHERE Pads.PadID = Fix.PadID
```

or solution above / below from Nanne depending what is a reason for JOIN

Answer (score 2):

I don't see a need for that join?
Try something like this:

```
 UPDATE Pads 
 SET Pads.RemoveMeDate = '1999-01-01 00:00:00'
 WHERE Pards.PadId IN ( 
       SELECT PadId FROM Fix
 )
```

Answer (score 0):

Try putting `Pads.PadID = Fix.PadID` in parenthesis

`(Pads.PadID = Fix.PadID)`

I've never actually tried doing a join on an update query, so I'm not sure if that will work.

Comment: Ok, but no Joy. When I say my query doesn't work, I mean no rows affected, when there are...